# refactor JDBC function

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

I am trying to create a simple web app that saves user data from a form to a database and reads the content of the database back to browser upon request. Following are the functions I have written so far.

```
connectToDB()            // connects to database
addEmployee()            // adds employee to database
displayEmployee()        // returns a resultSet 
isExisted(int staffID)   // checks if the staff already exists
```

Database connection function:

```
public void connectToDB(){
   try{
       // load Apache derby driver
       Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
   } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
       System.err.println(e);
   }

   try{
       connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DBNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
   } catch(SQLException e){
       System.err.println(e);
   }
} // end connectToDB
```

Display Employee function:

```
public ResultSet displayEmployee(){
   connectToDB(); 
   ResultSet result = null;

   try{
       Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
       String query = "SELECT * FROM APP.ADDRESSBOOK";
       result = stmt.executeQuery(query);

   } catch(SQLException e) {
       System.err.println(e);
   }

   return result;

}
```

Check if employee exists:

```
public boolean isExisted(int StaffID){
   connectToDB();
   try{
       Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
       String query = "SELECT StaffNum FROM APP.ADDRESSBOOK WHERE StaffNum = " + staff_number;
       ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(query);

       while(result.next()){
           int temp = result.getInt(1);
           if(temp == staff_number){return true;}
       }
   } catch(SQLException e) {
       System.err.println(e);
   }
   return false;
}
```

As you can see, if you compare the `displayEmployee()` and `isExisted()`, I am repeating mysel. Both the function works but I am looking to refactor the code. In those function I havent closed the connection. If there were 20 functions in the web app that connects to the database my code would stink.

I am looking something like this:
******* THIS CODE DOESNT WORK **************

```
private Statement queryDB(query){
   connectToDB(); 

   Statement stmt;
    try{
       stmt = connection.createStatement();

   } catch(SQLException e) {
       System.err.println(e);
   }
   return stmt;

   // code for closing connection
}

public ResultSet DisplayEmployee(){
   String query = "SELECT * FROM APP.ADDRESSBOOK";
   Statement stmt = queryDB(query);
   ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(query);
   return result;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using raw JDBC produces a lot of unsightly boilerplate code. One solution is to use [Spring JDBC Template](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html).

In addition you will get the sql exception hierarchy which will manage the underlying JDBC exceptions automatically as runtime exceptions.

For more see:

[Introduction to Spring Framework JDBC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/jdbc.html)

Answer (score 2):

A couple of comments:

1. The catch statement of `ClassNotFoundException` should throw an exception and shouldn't continue further.
2. It is not a good idea to return resultsets from a method that obtained them upon statement execution, since it is the responsibility of that method to close it. Instead, you should either read out the results into objects or cache them into `CachedRowSet` if your downstream functions expect a resultset.
3. The connectToDB method should return a successful connection or throw exception.
4. You could write a method that takes in an SQL query and return the results as objects so that this method can be used for retrieving based on different criteria as long you are retrieving the objects of same type.
5. isExisted is using staff_number which I think you intend it to be staffID. If you found a row with this value, then there is no need to check if the result set contained the row with this value, right?

My two cents!